# Russian-to-English Parallel Word Corpus?

Tags: python, translation, corpus, lexicon

I am looking for a simple Russian to English word corpus. It can be as simple as a csv that lists a russian word in the first column and the equivalent English word in the second. Any ideas where I can find such a thing? Does the NLTK toolkit have something like this?

Thanks

Comment: Failing all else, you could use the English/Russian links from Wiktionary.

Answer (score 5):

You can use English-Russian [Müller Dictionary](http://mueller-dict.sourceforge.net/) which is freely available in DICT format. You will need to invert it manually.